To say an additional consideration or thought, which do you use: Anyway OR Also?
I looked the word "anyway" up, and found that the dictionary says in sense 3:
3- as an additional consideration or thought Dictionary - anyway
Example sentence in the dictionary: We don't need a new car, and anyway, we can't afford one.
The use of "anyway" in this sense reminds me of another word, which is the "also", because it, too, is used as an additional consideration or thought.
So, in sentences like the above, I use "also", not "anyway". However, for me as a non-native speaker, both seem to work, but based on the dictionary, maybe I should use "anyway" instead of "Also", should I?

Your cited example with and anyway isn't actually a very idiomatic way of indicating that we can't afford one is a secondary (additional) assertion attaching to the primary assertion we don't need a new car. We usually put anyway immediately after the secondary assertion if two assertions are being made in the same utterance, so it would be We don't need a new car and we can't afford one anyway. If not being able to afford it was the primary objection, that would be We don't need a new car anyway, and we can't afford one (or more likely resequenced).

@FumbleFingers, Very good explanation.

Either of these could be used.  However the meanings are different.  While "and anyway" could be used to introduce another thought, the word "anyway" does not mean "also".  It means "in any case".

It was a bit long, so there wasn't space in the first comment to present the most idiomatically and pragmatically likely version, inclusive of contextually more natural conjunction for most contexts: We can't afford a new car, but we don't need one anyway.

@Fumblefingers, How about saying: We don't need a new car, but even if we did, we couldn't afford one.

Syntactically, that's fine. You must make up your own mind which lack (of need, or of money) is the primary factor, but anyway, in any case, even if we did/could are all semantically equivalent. It's just that "fronting" the element used to present the secondary objection inherently emphasizes that secondary objection (even though it's still a secondary consideration). That fronting is normally far more idiomatic with even if [we did/could] than with anyway, so it doesn't require heavy stress the way anyway would in ...but anyway, we couldn't afford one.


We don't need a new car, and anyway, we can't afford one.


We don't need a new car, and also, we can't afford one.

The second reason is significant.
Anyway is strong; with its use, the decision not to buy is firm.
With also, if a solution can be found for the second reason, they may still end up buying one.
... but if we can find a reasonable loan rate, we may consider.

It's more common for "anyway" to be at the end: "We don't need a new car, and we can't afford one anyway."

Per my comment under the question, the position of anyway is primarily governed by which of two assertions (objections to getting a new car, in the cited context) is the primary objection. Personally, I'd say that in the real world, being unable to afford something is normally a far stronger reason for not buying it than the fact of not needing it. If you can't afford it, you simply can't buy it, but even if you don't need it you could still buy it if you wanted it (and could afford it! :)

Further to the remark by Seowjooheng Singapore that anyway is "strong" and the decision is "firm"...
also and anyway do not have the same meaning.

We don't need a new car and we also can't afford one.

Two facts (or opinions), presented on equal terms. "also" just points out that a second one is coming down the pike.

We don't need a new car and, anyway, we can't afford one.

First fact (or opinion) is presented and  is followed by another statement that is intended to close off all debate on the issue of whether a new car is needed.  "anyway, we can't afford one" is synonymous with "under no circumstances can we afford one". Thus, even if you could convince me that we need one, the issue is moot because we cannot afford one, so don't even try to convince me.

You can't go to that party on Friday night. You have a big game on Saturday morning and can't be sleep-deprived for that. And anyway, Nana is coming by on Friday night with your birthday present.

So, even if you would promise to leave the party early, Nana is visiting on Friday evening to give you your birthday present, and that makes any debate on whether you can go to that party moot. Under no circumstances could you not be here when Nana is coming specifically to see you.
and anyway =  and in any case.
